# Ajax URL issue (PHP, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have been trying to retrieve a json from the PHP file and use it in my javascript where it will be used in a variable. I know that the datepicker UI is working whenever I use static variables but once I implement the getJson, the datepicker UI is not working. Is there a way to see if the ajax url is actually working? How do I console log the json object once I retrieve it in the javascript?

**checkDates.php**

```js
<?php
//Set document mime type... this is important since you want to return json not text!
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "user";
$dbname = "ebooking";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql = "select booking_date from booking";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$checkDates = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $checkDates[] = $row['booking_date'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($checkDates);
$conn->close();
?>
```

**index.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


</head>
<body>
Date:
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
</body>
<script>
    var badDates //= ["21-03-2016","31-03-2016","31-03-2016","30-03-2016"];
    $.getJSON('checkDates.php', function(json){badDates=json;});
    
    
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                if($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date ), badDates) > -1)
                {
                    return [false,"Unavailable","Booked"];
                }
                else
                {
                    return [true,"Available","Not Booked"];
                }
            }
        });
    })

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you can check if the call is working with the inspect tool from the browser, go to the network tab and you can check the server response for the call

Comment: I am getting this errors on the firefox error. GET 
http://localhost:8080/resources/demos/style.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8080/resources/demos/style.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]
no element found checkDates.php:32:3